# RSpec returns 0 examples, 0 failures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am new to Rspec. I am writing a test case to cover some action in a model. Here is my rspec code

test_cover_image_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Issue do

  before :each do
      @issue = Issue.joins(:multimedia).uniq.first
      binding.pry
  end

  describe '#release_cover_image' do
     context 'While making an issue open' do
          it 'should make issue cover in S3 accessible' do
          put :update, :id => @issue.id, :issue => @issue.attributes = {:open => '1'}

      end
    end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Which command do you use to run the tests?

Comment: When RSpec reports 0 examples and pry doesn't open, then you probably to not load the file at all.

Comment: What directory is the file in? Have you made sure to append _spec.rb at the end of the file name?

Comment: I run it using the command rspec ./spec/models/issues/issue_cover_release_spec.rb:1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rspec ./spec/models/issues/issue_cover_release_spec.rb:1
```

means you only want to run a line/block, that starts on the line 1.

In your case it's the `require 'spec_helper'` line, which has no assertions, thus no tests are run.

To run the whole suit, you should run, well, the whole suit:

```
 rspec ./spec/models/issues/issue_cover_release_spec.rb
```

Comment: THis fixed my problem. Thanks. I am editing my question. PLease check.

Comment: @krishna if this fixes your problem, please accept the answer (checkbox on the left near answer). If you have new question - ask it in the new thread.

Comment: Sure We will create a new question,